# How to draw the JK flip flop waveform for Q

Tags: digital-logic, signal, flipflop, waveform

[image]

The task is to draw a signal for the Q output. I know that the x is the one and the only one of inputs, but I have no idea what to do if I have this AND gate. How this signal will looks like in this situation? And what is the method to know how to draw it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m sure you know the truth tables for both the AND gate and the JKFF, or at least you can find them with a quick search.

So, just start with the AND gate: the output of the AND gate is 1 when both inputs are 1; otherwise the output is 0.

Therefore, at the first clock cycle, the output of the AND is 0, since `x` is 0. So, **J** becomes 0 and **K** becomes 1. This is a *reset* state, which drives **Q** to 0 and **Q_bar** to 1.

The second clock cycle doesn’t change anything since your JKFF is falling-edge triggered (note the inversion symbol on the FF’s clock).

At the third clock cycle, you now have two 1s at the AND inputs, so your **J** and **K** becomes 1 and 0, respectively, which is a *set* state.

I’m sure you can work out the rest.